# How to ensure URL parameters map to right field in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Say I have two independent classes:

```
class Foo {
   int bar;
}

class Baz {
   int bar;
}
```

and I want to accept an instance of each in Spring MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/someurl")
public ModelAndView myController(Foo f, Bar b) {
  // etc
}
```

How do construct a URL that contains unique values for f.bar and b.bar? Spring accepts `?bar=somevalue` and assigns `somevalue` to `f.bar` and `b.bar`, but I want to have unique values for each.

More generally, how do I scope parameters to a controller (via a URL with GET parameters) to only apply to a particular object's fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways I can think of.

1) Make a wrapper object that holds a foo and a bar so that you have unique binding paths to use in your query string.  Having multiple bind targets in your method signature 'works' but as you've discovered has some problems.  This will also be your best option if the actual values are coming out of form fields and you want the forms to 'just work' using the Spring form tags.

2) Create a custom `PropertyEditor` that can interpret a number with some kind of namespace on it then only parse and bind the number portion that goes with the current binding target.  e.g., your query string looks like `?bar=foo/12//bar/45` (better representation could be crafted I'm sure) and then parse out what you want in the PropertyEditor's `setAsText` method.  This will be a pain if you are getting those values from form fields though.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why Spring MVC can name MyObject.foo.bar as foo.bar, but doesn't understand MyObject.foo.bar? Seems crazy.

Comment: The binding framework is built around mapping a single form onto a single target object with a known context?  Best I can do.  The ability to have more than one target for binding sort of 'appeared' incidentally with annotation driven controllers.  The binder was originally created in a strict 1:1 controller:commandObject scenario.

Answer (score 2):

ok, to process url like this:

```
/someurl?fooId=3&barId=5
```

you need to write something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/someurl")
public ModelAndView myController(
            @RequestParam("fooId") int fooId, 
            @RequestParam("barId") int barId) {
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   foo.bar = fooId;

   Bar bar = new Bar();
   bar.bar = barId;

   // etc.
}
```

you can go a way **beyond that solution** and create custom converters:

```
public class FooConverter implements Converter<Integer, Foo> {
    @Override
    public Foo convert(Integer source) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.bar = source;
        return foo;
    }
}

public class BarConverter implements Converter<Integer, Bar> {
    @Override
    public Bar convert(Integer source) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.bar = source;
        return bar;
    }
}
```

and then after you register them in spring:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="xyz.FooConverter"/>
            <bean class="xyz.BarConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

you can use a shorter solution (where Foo and Bar is converted automatically):

```
@RequestMapping("/someurl")
public ModelAndView myController(
            @RequestParam("fooId") Foo foo, 
            @RequestParam("barId") Bar bar) {

   // etc.
}
```